# Subset specific dates (year and month) from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lubridate

Here my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID   Date
1      1975-01-01
2      1980-02-01
3      1985-05-01
4      1990-07-01
5      1990-08-01
6      1993-01-01
7      1993-09-01', header = TRUE)
```

I need to create a subset from it by selecting specific dates (year and month).

The dates I am interested are:

```
dates = c('1980-02', '1990-07', '1993-09')
```

and therefore my output should be:

```
ID     Date
2      1980-02-01
4      1990-07-01
7      1993-09-01
```

Is there any possibility to write a unique code that do the trick starting from `df` and `dates`, without add manually the dates in the code?

Thanks

####UPDATE

What if I have got multiple observations in the same month within `df`, like:

```
df2 = read.table(text = 'ID   Date
1      1975-01-01
2      1980-02-01
9      1980-02-01
3      1985-05-01
4      1990-07-01
12     1990-07-01
16     1990-07-01
5      1990-08-01
6      1993-01-01
7      1993-09-01
67     1993-09-01', header = TRUE)
```

New output:

```
ID     Date
2      1980-02-01
9      1980-02-01
4      1990-07-01
12     1990-07-01
16     1990-07-01
7      1993-09-01
67     1993-09-01
```

Thanks

Comment: Because your data appears to be standardized you can use `df[ substr(df$Date,1,7) %in% dates,]`. But to be safe, using proper date-time formats is preferred.

Comment: `df[df$Date %in% as.Date(paste0(dates,"-01")), ]`. This assumes `df$Date` is already in date format.

Comment: thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions.  They (i) work with any dates, not just ones that are the first of the month, (ii) preserve the order of `df2` in the output, (iii) are compact, i.e. one line each and do not require mentioning `df2` multiple times.

**1) substr** This uses no packages.

```
subset(df2, substr(Date, 1, 7) %in% dates)
```

giving:

```
   ID       Date
2   2 1980-02-01
3   9 1980-02-01
5   4 1990-07-01
6  12 1990-07-01
7  16 1990-07-01
10  7 1993-09-01
11 67 1993-09-01
```

**2) zoo::as.yearmon** Another possibility is to convert both `Date` and `dates` to `"yearmon"` class giving the same result.  This code is a bit nicer but does need a package.

```
library(zoo)
subset(df2, as.yearmon(Date) %in% as.yearmon(dates))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are formatted as strings, so they are somewhat difficult to work with. In general, it's better to format them as actual date objects. This can be done using [the **lubridate** package](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html). Here's what I would do. I use **readr** package for automatic type detection, and **purrr** for functional programming.

```
library(pacman)
p_load(lubridate, readr, purrr)

df = read_table(
'ID   Date
1      1975-01-01
2      1980-02-01
9      1980-02-01
3      1985-05-01
4      1990-07-01
12     1990-07-01
16     1990-07-01
5      1990-08-01
6      1993-01-01
7      1993-09-01
67     1993-09-01'
)

dates = parse_date_time(c('1980-02', '1990-07', '1993-09'), orders = "Y-m")

#subset
df[year(df$Date) %in% year(dates) & month(df$Date) %in% month(dates), ]
```

The output of which is:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
     ID       Date
  <int>     <date>
1     2 1980-02-01
2     9 1980-02-01
3     4 1990-07-01
4    12 1990-07-01
5    16 1990-07-01
6     7 1993-09-01
7    67 1993-09-01
```

So, we load the data as you did, but do it with **readr** to have to automatically recognize the dates. Then we subset the rows where the year matches any of the years in the `dates` object, and the month matches any of the months in the `dates` object. This gives the output you wanted.

However, perhaps you only want the combinations you gave. So e.g. year 1980 is only okay if it occurs with month 2. If so, it's a bit more complicated. This could be done in many ways, but I settled on a functional approach. This is not the fastest to execute, but it is quick to write and very flexible.

```
#subset stricter
inclusion_func = function(x, desired_dates) {
  #loop over each date
  map_lgl(x, function(date) {
    any(map_lgl(desired_dates, function(desired_date) {
      year(date) == year(desired_date) && month(date) == month(desired_date)
    })
    )
  })
}

df[inclusion_func(df$Date, dates), ]
```

The output of which is the same:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
     ID       Date
  <int>     <date>
1     2 1980-02-01
2     9 1980-02-01
3     4 1990-07-01
4    12 1990-07-01
5    16 1990-07-01
6     7 1993-09-01
7    67 1993-09-01
```

What the function does is loop over each date in the data frame, and loop over each year/month combination. It then checks if both the year and month matches for that particular combination. If any of the three combinations matches (hence the `any`), it returns `TRUE` for that row.

Answer (score 0):

According to the data you have shared the class of `Date` column is factor. We convert them into `Date` class and extract the month and year part and match it the `dates` vector to get the row numbers from `df` that match.

```
df[match(dates, format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y-%m")), ]  

#   ID       Date
#2  2 1980-02-01
#4  4 1990-07-01
#7  7 1993-09-01
```

As per the updated question, if we have multiple dates to match we can use `%in%` this gives you the desired output.

```
df2[format(as.Date(df2$Date), "%Y-%m") %in% dates, ]

#   ID       Date
#2   2 1980-02-01
#3   9 1980-02-01
#5   4 1990-07-01
#6  12 1990-07-01
#7  16 1990-07-01
#10  7 1993-09-01
#11 67 1993-09-01
```

Comment: hi, I just updated my question, could you please have a look? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    S = sapply(dates, function(d) { grep(d, df[,2]) })
    df[S,]
```

Answer (score 0):

as @eipi10 pointed out in the comments:

```
df[df$Date %in% as.Date(paste0(dates,"-01")), ]
```

this works good with my updated question.

Thanks